RenderBox was not laid out when using Positioned in Stack
I want to position Container with two buttons wrapped in Row in my Stack widget.
This is what I want to achieve. This text should be scrolled if it's long enough, that's why I have SingleChildScrollView.
Last thing I need to do is to position this two buttons on bottom

However, when I do that it's not working and I am getting this error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#04ae9 relayoutBoundary=up8
How to fix this?
Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: size.width,
                child: (...)
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: size.width - 16,
                  bottom: 64,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(16),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
                child: MainPadding(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Nazwa produktu'),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              NumberPicker(),
                              Text('250 zł')
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 16),
                          Text('Opis'),
                          const SizedBox(height: 8),
                          Expanded(
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Text('...'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 32,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black
                            )
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: someMethod,
                                  child: Text('kup i zapłać'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 8),
                              Expanded(
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: someMethod2,
                                  child: Text('Do koszyka'),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),


add left: 0 and right: 0 to Positioned or change Positioned with Positioned.fill (the second solution was not tested but it should work too)
